# How to decide whether a child node in a tree is a left child node or a right child node

Tags: data-structures

My question is:
How can I decide whether 45 is the right or left child of 50 and 50 is the right or left child of 40 in the binary search tree below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ484.png)

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show what you have done. SO is not a place to post your homework / assignment questions. [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Here are possible corrections in your question **[1]** By *Tree* I'm all but sure you meant a *Binary Tree*, mention that **[2]** *Deciding left or right child*: this part is very vague; please specify the sample inputs and sample outputs (by any chance are you talking about a *Binary Search Tree*?)

Answer (score 0):

Let me break your question in 2 part with whatever i understood.

Given a binary search tree,

1. to check if 45 is in the  right subtree or left subtree of 50.
2. 50 is the right or left child of 40

Technically,  you are asking to check if V is in the right or left subtree of U.

### Answer

if V>U, then V lies in right subtree of U else lies in left subtree of U.

Hope this helps